# Regex that works in httpd.conf does not work on regex101.com testing web site

Tags: regex

This regex code

```
 ^/0([0-9]?[0-9])
```

in my httpd.conf file means..

```
it must start with 0
it can be from 1 to 9 
it can be from 1 to 9 and then 1 to 9 again
```

but according to this web site..

http://regex101.com/r/aI2hY1/2#pcre

it is not valid regex...

how can it not be valid regex if it works fine for me via this line in httpd.conf

```
WSGIScriptAliasMatch ^/([0-9]?[0-9]) /dir/$1.wsgi
```

Comment: Apache regular expressions don’t have delimiters. Did you read the error on regex101?

Comment: It is valid here: http://regex101.com/r/aI2hY1/3 You have problem of unescaped `/`

Comment: FYI: `[0-9]` is from 0 to 9, not from 1 to 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be,

```
\/0([0-9]?[0-9])
```

Just remove the `^` symbol and escape the forward slash `/`.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aI2hY1/4)